# Enterprise Target Rule - Attribute Values Must Have Store ID of 0 (zero)

Tags: magento-enterprise, store-view, rules

A Magento EE 1.14.0.1 site I'm working on was having problem with target rules. The rule would be something very simple, like this:

```
Products to Match:
If ALL of these conditions are TRUE:
Category is 10

Products to Display:
If ALL of these conditions are TRUE:
Product Collection contains Matched Product Collection
```

Now "Collection" is a custom attribute that we created (attribute code is `collections`.) It's a multiselect, with a scope of "Store View". We also imported the nearly 1000 options for that attribute, and over 10,000 attribute-to-product values. When we imported these values, we set the `store_id` to 1.

I should note that we only have one website (ID: 1) one store group (ID: 1) and one store view (ID: 1) so setting the `store_id` to 1 in `catalog_product_entity_value` seemed okay.

We noticed that the subselect that the Target Rule module creates has `store_id = 0` in it though, and that no products ever matched based on this `collections` attribute. It wasn't until we changed all of the values in `catalog_product_entity_value` to have `store_id = 0` that this Target Rule started working.

There isn't even a means to select a store view in the admin because we only have one on the site, and there are thousands of attribute values in `catalog_product_entity_value` with a `store_id` of 1, so why must I set this particular attribute to 0 to get it to work?

Comment: Have you fount a reason of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I heard back from Magento, and they told us:

> Magento should always have the value for store_id = 0, because it is
>   for admin store.
>
> If the merchant has more than 1 store and wants to set some specific
>   attribute value for this store, Magento will add new record with a
>   value for this attribute and set store_id depending on this store.

That makes sense, and I plan to adjust any and all custom import code accordingly, as I can't be sure what other Magento functions expect this.